# Вопрос про отладку DLL из несвязанного проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, отладка

Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию.

Есть два независимых проекта `Visual Studio` - c `exe` и c `dll`. В проекте `exe` динамически подгружается и используется библиотека из проекта с `dll`.

Меня интересует следующий вопрос. Если я открываю проект с `exe` и открываю какой-нибудь файл исходного кода из проекта с `dll`, а затем устанавливаю туда точку останова и включаю отладку, то `Visual Studio` каким-то чудом останавливается на указанных точках останова, хотя они находятся в исходных файлах совсем другого проекта.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как это возможно? На чем основан этот механизм?

Comment: это про .Net я так понимаю проекты идет речь? в случае c M$ я вообще не удивляюсь как у них это получается) у меня есть подозрения как они это реализуют, но пруфов нет как и Visual Studio в линуксе чтобы это проверить

Comment: Нет, проекты C++, извините, что забыл это уточнить.

Comment: На присутствии отладочной информации (.pdb).

Comment: @user7860670, как он ее находит, если я открываю только один файл исходного кода из другого проекта?

Comment: dll в Debug'e скомпилирована - мое предположение

Comment: В dll указывается, где искать соотв. pdb файл.

Comment: да значит мои преположения оказались верными)